# PhpStorm перестал подсвечивать .php файл

Tags: php, phpstorm

Cоздал файл без расширения и при выборе типа файла выбрал не PHP, отображается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсветка и логика в коде отсутствует, там просто белый текст.

Проект удалённый, правая кнопка мыши ничего не предлагает изменить. Интересно то, что в любом удалённом проекте данный файл будет отображаться так.

Как можно изменить это и где?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте зайти в `Settings` / `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `File Types` и поискать ваш файл в ассоциациях с типом "Text", и после этого удалить его из списка `Registered Patterns`.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Windows: Зайдите в папку с данным файлом, нажмите `Ctrl + F1` или мышкой кликните `развернуть ленту`. Там вы увидите дополнительные возможности нажмите на `Вид`
поставьте галочку на `Расширения имён файлов`. Теперь вы можете изменять расширения